# Google Apps config via DNS zone file

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite

I have a problem with setting the DNS in order to use Google Apps on specific domains. I can easily set the DNS for domains that are controlled via some control panel (eg. GoDaddy) but I have problems for domains that are controlled via zone files on the server.

If I configure the zone file like following:

```
MYDOMAIN.COM.    3600    IN    SOA    some.domaincontrol.com.    name.mail.com (
            2012041904
            28800
            7200
            604800
            3600
            )
; A Records
@    3600    IN    A    000.000.000.000

; CNAME Records
mail    3600    IN    CNAME    ghs.google.com
calendar    3600    IN    CNAME    ghs.google.com
docs    3600    IN    CNAME    ghs.google.com
www    3600    IN    CNAME    @
test    3600    IN    CNAME    @

; MX Records
@    3600    IN    MX    1    ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
@    3600    IN    MX    5    ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
@    3600    IN    MX    5    ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
@    3600    IN    MX    10    ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
@    3600    IN    MX    10    ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM

; TXT Records
@    3600    IN    TXT    "google-site-verification=blah-blah-12345"

; NS Records
@    3600    IN    NS    some.domaincontrol.com
@    3600    IN    NS    another.domaincontrol.com
```

Then the MX records reported by Google Apps, and some DNS query sites (like Network Tools), are having as suffix the domain itself:

```
MX    1    ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.MYDOMAIN.COM
MX    5    ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.MYDOMAIN.COM
MX    5    ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.MYDOMAIN.COM
MX    10    ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.MYDOMAIN.COM
MX    10    ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.MYDOMAIN.COM
```

Also, the "mail", "docs" and "calendar" subdomains are not being redirected to Google Apps.

I have also tried with the following configuration for the MX records, in hope that this will properly point to external (Google) mail exchange:

```
; MX Records
3600    MX    1    ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
3600    MX    5    ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
3600    MX    5    ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
3600    MX    10    ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
3600    MX    10    ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

But this resulted with no MX record being retrieved by Google Apps and DNS queries. Some sort of misconfiguration in the DNS zone file is occurring

How can I properly configure domain via zone file to properly point to external MX and CNAME lcoations? Particularly to Google Apps?

PS. I have first posted same question at Stackoverflow, prior to realizing that this is more suitable location. [Question URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367550/google-apps-config-via-dns-zone-file).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In zone files, all domain names without trailing dot interpreted as *relative to the zone*.
@ is a shortcut for the zone domain and if label is omitted, the last label is used. That is probably why in your last MX example you got no MX records.

```
; CNAME Records
mail     3600    IN    CNAME ghs.google.com.
calendar 3600    IN    CNAME ghs.google.com.
docs     3600    IN    CNAME ghs.google.com.
www      3600    IN    CNAME @
test     3600    IN    CNAME @
; MX Records
@        3600    IN    MX    1    ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@        3600    IN    MX    5    ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@        3600    IN    MX    5    ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@        3600    IN    MX    10    ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@        3600    IN    MX    10    ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

; TXT Records
@        3600    IN    TXT   "google-site-verification=blah-blah-12345"

; NS Records
@        3600    IN    NS    some.domaincontrol.com.
@        3600    IN    NS    another.domaincontrol.com.
```

Comment: it was a missing trailing dot that originally caused problems. I knew it's gonna be something trivial (not to me, of course). now it works like a charm! thanks.

Comment: Perfect! Prevents me from having to manually enter in the google mx records every time